# Mark reminder as complete in Outlook Reminders dialog

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is there a keyboard shortcut to mark a task as *complete* in the Outlook *Reminders* dialog?

Right now I have to right click every item and select "Mark Complete".

[image]

The quickest way I have found, by keyboard, is to press <kbd>Context menu</kbd> (if the keyboard has such a button) followed by <kbd>M</kbd>, but it has a slight delay as compared to a button combo press.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with this functionality, but does Dismiss just close the reminder, and leave the item incomplete?

Comment: @spikey_richie Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by following steps:

1. Click Quick Steps > New Quick Step > Custom.
   [image]
2. Select Mark Complete.

   [image]
3. Choose a shortcut.

[image]

Then when the Reminders dialog show, just select the task and press shortcut.

Hope this can be helpful

Comment: Thanks for your response. I followed your steps but I do not manage to complete the task using the shortcut. I have tried different shortcuts and both in the reminders pop-up dialog and in the Reminders tab/window in Outlook. I managed to use a shortcut for "Set Importance" on an e-amil in the e-mail tab, so I don't know what's up..